# How to randomly replace 10% of elements in a matrix into zero

Tags: matlab

Let C be a 40x40 matrix with zeros in the diagonal. How do I randomly replace 10% of the elements in the matrix with zeros?

Comment: Exactly 10% or probably 10% ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark exactly 10%. I only able to make it less than or equal, I wanted it to be exactly 10%.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of @HighPerformanceMark 's mask*matrix method, I would simply index the matrix itself:

```
data=rand(10);

N = numel(data);
data(randperm(N,floor(N/10))) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

For exactly 10% elements replaced by 0 something like this might satisfy you:

```
mask = [ones(1,1440),zeros(1,160)];
mask = reshape(mask(randperm(1600)),[40,40]);
c.*mask
```

If probably 10% is acceptable, try

```
c.*(randi(10,40)<=9)
```

I guess you can figure these out, if not comment.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got your idea but I left out the point that diagonal entries in the matrix are zeros. So, it will generate different number of zero entries in each run.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest method would be to use logical indexing in combination with scalar assignment:

```
C(rand(size(C)) < 0.1) = 0;
```

but that would not give you *exactly* 10% as you specified.

An exact solution is

```
nC = numel(C);
[~, p] = sort(rand(1, nC));
C(p <= nC/10) = 0;
```

which is identical to `randperm` without the overhead of `randperm()` in Matlab R2010 and earlier.

Comment: It's not that fast, you still have to generate `nC` random numbers, sort those (all of them), and then compare with `nC/10` to get the final logical. `randperm` by itself is about 4-10 times faster...

Comment: @ GuntherStruyf Type `edit randperm` at the matlab command prompt. It's the exact same code.

Comment: already did that, in R2011b, randperm is builtin (and probably that's why it's faster)